# What is the value of $\cos A$ given $\sin A$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If we have $\sin A = 0.5$, and were asked to find $\cos A$, then using the identity $\cos^2 A = 1 – \sin^2 A$ we can do so. But this means that $\cos A = \pm \sqrt{1 – \sin^2 A}$. However this implies that there are exactly two cosine values we are looking for. Is this correct? Moreover, I found that it is usual that when I define a trigonometric equation, say $\sin A = 0.5$, then according to my algebra, there are exactly 2 values for $\cos A$, exactly 2 values for $\sin 2A$, and exactly 4 values for $\sin \frac A 2$. Is this correct? I ask because I have never been taught this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, there are 2 values for cos. Depending on the context, one may be correct and the other incorrect. For instance, in the given context the angle defined may lie in some predefined domain (so choose the value of cos that fits according to sign), or the sign of cos may be given.

Comment: By predefined domain, would you mean something such as, say, if the angles are angles of a triangle; in which case all angles spoken of must be in magnitude less than $180°$? Also, what are the remaining results for other angles. Is it true that, for example, the trigonometrical ratio of any half-angle must have 4 values (given that the angle itself hasn't been specified)?

Comment: Yes, that can be the case. In many questions, it is specified that the angles are acute/lie in a specific range etc. Also, for the second question, yes (there are 4 values of sin x/2)

Comment: @VedaanshAgarwal can you pls name all the four values of sinx/2

Comment: "...and exactly 4 values for $\sin \frac A 2$" : No, this is not correct.  Since you have that $~\sin(A) = 0.5,~$ then, within a modulus of $~2\pi,~$ you must have that $~A \in \{30^\circ, 150^\circ\}.~$ This implies that, within a modulus of $~2\pi,~$ you must have that $~(A/2) \in \{15^\circ, 75^\circ\}.$

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad solving for A/2, A/2 = 15° + n(180°) or 75°+n(180°), where n is an integer.  Now, sin(15 + n(180)) gives two values, and (75+ n(180)) gives two. Please correct if wrong

Comment: @VedaanshAgarwal put $n=1$ in $\sin 15+n\pi$ and see that it evaluates to a negative number but it can't happen as $\sin A$ is positive

Comment: For sin A, wouldnt we do 2(15 +n180) instead of just (15+ n180), because 15+ n180 is A/2 and not A?  Sin 195 is negative but sin(2*195) is positive

Comment: @VedaanshAgarwal since sinA is positive domain of A is $0,\pi$ and hence domain of $A/2$ is $0,\pi/2$ hence it can't be negative

Comment: Ohh okay, i understand. Thanks for clarifying. But what went wrong with the general solutions here? It seems that using general solutions i get infinitely many values. If not mentioned, do we assume it ourselves and resttict A to [0,pi] and not lets say, [2pi, 3pi]?

Comment: @VedaanshAgarwal with general solutions you get infinite values of the angle...but all of those evaluate to $2$ answers only

Comment: Also for sines , the general solution is not $n\pi$

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In this crude diagram $\quad 
\dfrac{FG}{FE}=\dfrac{HI}{HE}\quad $ but
$\quad \dfrac{GE}{FE} = \dfrac{(-1)IE}{HE}.\quad$ Each function is the same in two quadrants but the other is equal in quadrants rotated by $90˚.$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\sin\frac{\pi}{6}=\sin\frac{5\pi}{6}=\frac12\:\: A\in[0,2\pi]$

So there are two values of $A$ and hence two values of the cosine function. This happens because trigonometric functions are many-one or injective functions.

You can see that I've restricted my domain to $[0,2\pi]$ but if I don't add any restriction then there are infinite values of $A$ (that does not mean infinite values of $\cos A$, it will still be $2$)

I recommend OP to read about the general solutions of trigonometric functions.

And since we found out that $A$ has two values so $\frac{A}{2}$ also have two values so it's sine function also has two values.

Comment: You must be mistaken. It must be the case that $\sin$$A\over2$ has exactly 4 values. For example, given $\sin A = 0.5$, what are the values of $\sin$$A\over 2$? Merely glancing we see that within a period, $A$ could be any of $\{30°, 150°,–210°,–330°\}$; and so the half angles are $\{15°,75°,–105°,–165°\}$, which all give different sine values.

Comment: @Camelot823 since $\sin A$ is positive it means that $A\in[0,\pi]$ so $A/2\in[0,\pi/2]$ and hence is always positive.....$\sin-105$ and $\sin-165$ gives negative values

Comment: Why is $\sin A$ positive? I haven't established that.

Comment: @Camelot823 because it is equal to 0.5

Comment: ahh, correct. However, still, let $\sin A$ be positive, this means that the angle $A$ is within the first and second quadrants. Then the halfangle $A\over2$ is within the first quadrant (for all positive $A$) or within the third quadrant (for all negative $A$). So, $\sin $$A\over2$ can still be 4 values. I mean, just because $\sin A$ is positive doesn't mean that $\sin $$A\over2$ is. I believe this comes from the fact that $A$ isn't necessarily positive just because it's in the first and second quadrants.

Comment: @Camelot823 That was what I meant in the comments above in the question, i think he has considered A to be between 0, π and not the other intervals like 2π,3π etc.

Comment: @VedaanshAgarwal I don't see why such convention should be used, though; for we are searching for all possible angles, and aren't limiting ourselves to a certain range of positive angles only. I'm saying this in particular because that's exactly how I was taught by according to the book I'm reading.

Answer (score 1):

Using a unit circle, write "A" in Quadrant 1, "S" in Quadrant 2, "T" in Quadrant 3, and "C" in Quadrant 4 (can be memorized with "all students take Calculus").  In Quadrant 1, all trig functions are positive.  In Quadrant 2, sine is positive (along with its reciprocal cosecant).  In Quadrant 3, Tangent is positive (along with its reciprocal cotangent).  In Quadrant 4, cosine is positive (along with its reciprocal secant).  So in the interval [0,2π], there are always two angles where each trig function will have the same value, whether it is positive or negative, since each trig function is positive in two quadrants and negative in two quadrants.